# How to extract form data from a POST route in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, react-router, form-data

In my React project, I have integrated the payment gateway.

This is the flow.

[image]

Payment gateway is posting data to one of the route I provided. 
I can also see the data is properly getting from payment gateway.

Check this

[image]

Now, the problem is that how do I read the form data sent by payment gateway inside my React Component.

For GET request it was easy to get the query string from `this.props.location.search`.
But here I am not able to get the form data posted by payment gateway.

I tried to check `this.props.location.search`, `this.props.match.params` and almost every were in `this.props` object.

I am not sure from where to read that data inside the react component.

Comment: The network request you are showing in the second image is the form data you send to the server, isn't it? I don't think that's the Payment Gateway response. Have you checked the `Response` tab?

Comment: No that's the payment gateway response, you can see it has `STATUS` and `RESPMSG` which payment gateway sends us.

Comment: Can you post your code for the POST request to the payment gateway? You'll typically want to have your POST request contain the logic for handling the response from the server.

Comment: That data is coming from the payment gateway, but I read many articles and there it was written that using frontend technology we cannot read the POST data even if it is visible inside the browser. POST data is meant to be read by the backend server, as react is frontend I doubt we can read the POST data. Anyone here can explain to me if this is true.

Comment: @VishalShetty Did you get any solution to this? I am also stuck on same scenario.

Comment: We're having sort of the same problem. Using Adyen I found [this](https://docs.adyen.com/checkout/3d-secure/redirect-3ds2-3ds1/web-drop-in#handle-the-redirect-result) in the documentation (see the blue box). Does it work for you? Hopefully you didn't go out of business in the meantime